# Refresh database (mySql) using jquery rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to read data from mysql database, it is basically the pincode and comparing it with the near location.

I need to check the database every 2 secs for new records without refreshing my page in my rails application. Is there any possibility.

Comment: You should use AJAX, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That actually worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with rails pubsub pattern with jquery.

> The publish-subscribe pattern (or pub/sub, for short) is a Ruby on Rails messaging pattern where senders of messages (publishers), do not program the messages to be sent directly to specific receivers (subscribers). Instead, the programmer “publishes” messages (events), without any knowledge of any subscribers there may be.

You can read about both this [pubsub here](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/the-publish-subscribe-pattern-on-rails) and [jquery publishsubscribe here](https://bocoup.com/blog/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events)